# Difference between @OneToOne and @Column

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I wonder what exactly is the difference between

> @OneToOne and @Column

for objects in java. I just came to this, because spring boot and it's JPA implementation doesn't support java 8 per default, like the class Instant.

I updated now manually and have now that code snip:

```
@Entity
public class Volumen {

    @OneToOne
    Instant dateAndTime;

    public Volumen(Instant dateAndTime) {
        this.dateAndTime = dateAndTime;
    }

    public Instant getDateAndTime() {
        return dateAndTime;
    }

    public void setDateAndTime(Instant dateAndTime) {
        this.dateAndTime = dateAndTime;
    }
}
```

Since there are not many examples for java lib objects I hope you could explain to me, what is the difference between

```
    @OneToOne
    Instant dateAndTime;
```

and

```
    @Column
    Instant dateAndTime;
```

Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html vs. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/Column.html - take a look at the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@OneToOne` specifies a relation, a Foreign Key to another entity. `@Column` just specifies that the attribute represents a column from the table.

You can only use `@Column` on basic types (String, Integer, Date, Long...). When you want to use a complex object (custom one implemented by you) you must use a relation annotation (`@OneToOne`, `@OneToMany`, `@ManyToOne` or `@ManyToMany`)

`@OneToOne` and `@Column` are annotations for JPA. JPA is an specification from Java EE, and has many versions. The version from Java EE 7 is JPA 2.1, which is dated before Java 8, so there is no support for the new java 8 Java Time API in JPA 2.1. You will have to wait for the release of Java EE 8 (expected end of 2017) and thus the next version of JPA to use `@Column` with `Instant`.

Comment: Oh okay. Just to be sure: That mean I have to change the code above from  Column Instant dateAndTime; to  Column Date dateAndTime;
?

Comment: Correct. And add @Temporal to specify if you eant dates, times or timestamps in databse